# Frequency counter utility class

Tags: java, sorting

Some very common tasks that keep popping up from time time:

- Find the most frequent *something* in a collection of *things*
- ... or the count of that thing
- ... or both (the item and its count)
- Get the list of distinct items, with their counts, sorted by their counts
- Get the N most frequent items, with their counts

To avoid typing up the same kind of frequency counting code over and over again,
I came up with this:

```
public class FrequencyCounter<T> {

    private final Map<T, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>();

    private final Comparator<T> countComparator = (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(frequencyMap.get(o1), frequencyMap.get(o2));

    public void add(T item) {
        Integer count = frequencyMap.get(item);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        frequencyMap.put(item, count + 1);
    }

    public void addAll(Collection<T> items) {
        items.forEach(this::add);
    }

    public T getMostFrequentItem() {
        return toSortedMap().lastKey();
    }

    public int getMostFrequentCount() {
        SortedMap<T, Integer> sortedMap = toSortedMap();
        T lastKey = sortedMap.lastKey();
        return sortedMap.get(lastKey);
    }

    private SortedMap<T, Integer> toSortedMap(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        SortedMap<T, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
        sortedMap.putAll(frequencyMap);
        return sortedMap;
    }

    public SortedMap<T, Integer> toSortedMap() {
        return toSortedMap(countComparator);
    }

    public SortedMap<T, Integer> toReversedMap() {
        return toSortedMap(Collections.reverseOrder(countComparator));
    }

    private List<T> toSortedList(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(frequencyMap.keySet());
        Collections.sort(list, comparator);
        return list;
    }

    public List<T> toSortedList() {
        return toSortedList(countComparator);
    }

    public List<T> toReversedList() {
        return toSortedList(Collections.reverseOrder(countComparator));
    }
}
```

Unit tests:

```
public class FrequencyCounterTest {
    @Test
    public void test_getMostFrequentItem() {
        FrequencyCounter<Integer> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        counter.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 4, 9, 3, 4, 5, 4, 9));
        assertEquals(new Integer(4), counter.getMostFrequentItem());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getMostFrequentCount() {
        FrequencyCounter<Integer> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        counter.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 4, 9, 3, 4, 5, 4, 9));
        assertEquals(3, counter.getMostFrequentCount());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getMostFrequentLetter() {
        FrequencyCounter<Character> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, " +
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. " +
                "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris " +
                "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in " +
                "reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla " +
                "pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in " +
                "culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

        for (char c : text.replace(" ", "").toCharArray()) {
            counter.add(c);
        }
        assertEquals(new Character('i'), counter.getMostFrequentItem());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_map_hi_hi_hello() {
        FrequencyCounter<String> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hello");
        assertEquals("{hello=1, hi=2}", counter.toSortedMap().toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_map_hello_hi_hi() {
        FrequencyCounter<String> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        counter.add("hello");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hi");
        assertEquals("{hello=1, hi=2}", counter.toSortedMap().toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_map_hello_hi_hi_hello_hello() {
        FrequencyCounter<String> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        counter.add("hello");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hello");
        counter.add("hello");
        assertEquals("{hi=2, hello=3}", counter.toSortedMap().toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_sortedList_hi_hi_hello() {
        FrequencyCounter<String> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hello");
        assertEquals("[hello, hi]", counter.toSortedList().toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_sortedList_hello_hi_hi() {
        FrequencyCounter<String> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        counter.add("hello");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hi");
        assertEquals("[hello, hi]", counter.toSortedList().toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_sortedList_hello_hi_hi_hello_hello() {
        FrequencyCounter<String> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        counter.add("hello");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hello");
        counter.add("hello");
        assertEquals("[hi, hello]", counter.toSortedList().toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_reversedList_hi_hi_hello() {
        FrequencyCounter<String> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hello");
        assertEquals("[hi, hello]", counter.toReversedList().toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_reversedList_hello_hi_hi() {
        FrequencyCounter<String> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        counter.add("hello");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hi");
        assertEquals("[hi, hello]", counter.toReversedList().toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_reversedList_hello_hi_hi_hello_hello() {
        FrequencyCounter<String> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        counter.add("hello");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hello");
        counter.add("hello");
        assertEquals("[hello, hi]", counter.toReversedList().toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_reversedList_hello_hi_hi_hello_hello_null() {
        FrequencyCounter<String> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
        counter.add("hello");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hi");
        counter.add("hello");
        counter.add("hello");
        counter.add(null);
        assertEquals("[hello, hi, null]", counter.toReversedList().toString());
    }
}
```

What do you think?

- Anything to improve, or odd-looking?
- Am I reinventing the wheel? Is there something existing that I can use instead?
- Is this usable, ergonomic enough, or can it be better?

Comment: Have you considered Java 8 streams? These kind of tasks are quite well-suited for streams and lambdas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Simon has a good answer about some usability issues, but I want to focus on the performance and memory aspects of it.

I agree with Simon that the counter should be a long value, but, more than that, you should create a mutable long class, and not use Long (or, in your case, Integer).

Consider the class:

```
public class Counter (

    private long count = 0;

    public long increment() {
        return ++count;
    }

    public long get() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Now, create your internal map as:

```
private final Map<T, Counter> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>();
```

In your `add()` method, have:

```
public void add(T item) {
    frequencyMap.computeIfAbsent(item, k -> new Counter()).increment();
}
```

By using a counter, you greatly reduce the amount of memory churn in your map, and you can convert it easily to a reportable Long instance when you externalize the values.

Answer (score 5):

#### Stream, Stream, Stream

It seems to be quite common to create a `FrequencyCounter` from a `Collection`, so why not make it a static factory method?

```
public static <T> FrequencyCounter<T> fromCollection(Collection<T> values) {
    FrequencyCounter<T> result = new FrequencyCounter<>();
    result.addAll(values);
    return result;
}
```

Or, if you switch the `Map<T, Integer>` to `Map<T, Long>`, how about from a Stream, using some Stream magic?

```
private FrequencyCounter(Map<T, Long> frequencyMap) {
    this.frequencyMap = frequencyMap;
    this.countComparator = (o1, o2) -> Long.compare(frequencyMap.get(o1), frequencyMap.get(o2));
}

public static <T> FrequencyCounter<T> fromStream(Stream<T> stream) {
    Map<T, Long> frequencies = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
    return new FrequencyCounter<>(frequencies);
}
```

I believe this line is about as close to an already-existing wheel as you are going to get:

```
Map<T, Long> frequencies = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

In your `test_getMostFrequentLetter` you can then do:

```
counter = FrequencyCounter.fromStream(text.chars().filter(i -> i != ' ')
    .mapToObj(i -> (char) i));
```

And in another test:

```
FrequencyCounter<String> counter = FrequencyCounter.fromStream(Stream.of("hi", "hi", "hello"));
```

[Stream, Stream, Stream, all you have to do, is Stream...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbU3zdAgiX8)

#### Immutability?

Consider making `FrequencyCounter` immutable, or having a separate `FrequencyCount` that simply holds the result from the `FrequencyCounter` (then you'd also just have to call `toSortedMap` once)

#### Adding is merging

Your `add` method can be quite simplified when using `merge`:

```
public void add(T item) {
    frequencyMap.merge(item, 1L, (oldValue, value) -> oldValue + value);
}
```

#### Get methods

Let's take a look at your `get` methods...

```
public T getMostFrequentItem()
public int getMostFrequentCount()
public SortedMap<T, Integer> toSortedMap()
public SortedMap<T, Integer> toReversedMap()
public List<T> toSortedList()
public List<T> toReversedList()
```

How about `int getFrequency(T item)` ?

Or some other way to access the already existing `Map<T, Long>` without the overhead of turning it into a `SortedMap` ?

#### Edge case

Consider this code:

```
FrequencyCounter<String> counter = new FrequencyCounter<>();
String mostUsed = counter.getMostFrequentItem();
int count = counter.getMostFrequentCount();
```

This will cause 2x NullPointerException. There is no most frequent item. There is no most frequent count.

I would expect `counter.getMostFrequentCount()` to return 0 in this case, and I'd probably make `counter.getMostFrequentItem()` return `null`. Either way, it is an edge-case that I don't think you have considered. It's up to you how you will handle it :)